# Automated material UI components using watir or selenium

Tags: watir-webdriver, material-ui

I am trying to find out if anyone has an approach to automated UI testing on Material UI components.

Material UI elements are rendered as nested divs with very little unique id information, for example:

```
<div data-reactroot style="...">
  <div style="...">
    <div style="...">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The nested div structure makes using traditional location methods difficult if not impossible - (Selenium and Watir), id, name, class, etc.

Using react devtools, one can see a much clearer picture of how the page is structured, but I am not yet able to access the React "DOM" to locate elements.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Added example:

[Sliders](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/slider)

I can't come up with an example that is more descriptive than the one above, could literally be 10 layers of nested divs without any text.

Comment: From the examples I have seen, it looks like you should be able to add IDs to controls. For example, in the [text field example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field), they have an ID on the default value field. Is that an option? At a minimum, you should be able to identify elements as a user would (eg text, relation to labels, etc.). Showing a more of the page you are working on might help us provide answers (and avoid the question being closed as too broad).

Comment: We are looking at the addition of IDs to components but the functional controls (inside of components), e.g. the "handle" of a slider component is more complex to ID. As far as ID by text, when we locate text within the nested div structure we get the outermost div returned, which could, ultimately, just be the root of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general method I'm aware of, unfortunately.

Some of the components already have `id`s, which allows you to use a css selector like `#my-component input` (which is usually enough to get an exact field), others have custom class names to be added (like `AutoComplete` - `popoverProps`) which allows you to use a similar selector.

Good news is that every MaterialUI component provides `className`, which can be used to locate elements (at least partially) - details can be found at http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles
Also `id` field works quite often, even when not documented.

At the last resort (if detection by class + other css selector parts is not sufficient) you can fall back to XPath expression using element text - for example, I use `//span[@class="menu-item"][.//div[contains(text(),"${itemName}")]]` for matching menu items. It matches things declared as `<MenuItem primaryText={itemName} className="menu-item">`